# How do you play a multi player game with two hand controllers

Tags: forza-motorsport-3

We are currently trying to play Forza Motorsport 3.

We have two controllers but can't work out how we can play two player. The game does state that two players can play at the same time....

Comment: Hand controls? Do you mean [controllers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_controller)?

Answer (score 5):

You can play local multiplayer by going to "Free Play" from the main menu and selecting "Split Screen" option from the next menu that comes up.